# Better design for multiple function call

Tags: c++

I've written a sudoku validator for an online judge website.
https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1383

My solution works great for the 9 grid sudoku, by verifying if each column row and sudoku 3x3 block contains numbers from 1-9 using a bitset and flipping each bit at the number index.

[image]

However, I'm making multiple calls to `ValidateOneBlock()` specifying the iterators range.

My gut tells me that this approach could be fundamentally better. How can I improve(if possible) my code by not using a big `if` with many calls to `ValidateOneBlock()`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>

namespace Constants
{
    constexpr int ROW_COL_SIZE = 9;
    const std::string STR_YES = "SIM"; //yes in Portuguese
    const std::string STR_NO = "NAO"; //no in Portuguese
}

template<unsigned int N>
class Sudoku
{
private:
    int m_matrix[N][N] {{0}};
public:
    void ReadRows();
    bool IsValid() const;
private:
    bool ValidateOneBlock(const int& minRowIndex, const int& maxRowIndex, const int& minColIndex, const int& maxColIndex) const;
};

template<unsigned int N>void Sudoku<N>::ReadRows()
{
    for(unsigned int row{0}; row<N; row++)
    {
        static std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::istringstream issline(line);

        int readnum {0};
        for(unsigned int i{0}; i<N; i++)
        {
            issline >> readnum;
            m_matrix[row][i] = readnum;
        }
    }
}

template<unsigned int N>bool Sudoku<N>::IsValid() const
{
    //9bit default ctor all zeroes, 000000000
    std::bitset<N> bitRow[N];
    std::bitset<N> bitCol[N];
    for(unsigned int i{0}; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j{0}; j<N; j++)
        {
            bitRow[i].flip(m_matrix[i][j]-1); //bitset index is 0 not 1.
            bitCol[i].flip(m_matrix[j][i]-1);
        }
        if(!bitRow[i].all() || !bitCol[i].all()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /* What ValidateOneBlock() does  is verify numbers 1-9 within the Sudoku blocks. These are the indexes
    0-0 0-1 0-2 | 0-3 0-4 0-5 | 0-6 0-7 0-8
    1-0 1-1 1-2 | 1-3 1-4 1-5 | 1-6 1-7 1-8
    2-0 2-1 2-2 | 2-3 2-4 2-5 | 2-6 2-7 2-8
    ---------------------------------------
    3-0 3-1 3-2 | 3-3 3-4 3-5 | 3-6 3-7 3-8
    4-0 4-1 4-2 | 4-3 4-4 4-5 | 4-6 4-7 4-8
    5-0 5-1 5-2 | 5-3 5-4 5-5 | 5-6 5-7 5-8
    ---------------------------------------
    6-0 6-1 6-2 | 6-3 6-4 6-5 | 6-6 6-7 6-8
    7-0 7-1 7-2 | 7-3 7-4 7-5 | 7-6 7-7 7-8
    8-0 8-1 8-2 | 8-3 8-4 8-5 | 8-6 8-7 8-8
    */

    if(N == Constants::ROW_COL_SIZE)
    {
        if( ValidateOneBlock(0, 2, 0, 2) &&
            ValidateOneBlock(0, 2, 3, 5) &&
            ValidateOneBlock(0, 2, 6, 8) &&

            ValidateOneBlock(3, 5, 0, 2) &&
            ValidateOneBlock(3, 5, 3, 5) &&
            ValidateOneBlock(3, 5, 6, 8) &&

            ValidateOneBlock(6, 8, 0, 2) &&
            ValidateOneBlock(6, 8, 3, 5) &&
            ValidateOneBlock(6, 8, 6, 8) )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
template<unsigned int N>
bool Sudoku<N>::ValidateOneBlock(const int& minRowIndex, const int& maxRowIndex,
                                 const int& minColIndex, const int& maxColIndex) const
{
    std::bitset<N> bitBlock;
    for(int i=minRowIndex; i<=maxRowIndex; i++){
        for(int j=minColIndex; j<=maxColIndex; j++){
            bitBlock.flip(m_matrix[i][j]-1);
        }
    }
    return bitBlock.all();
}
int main()
{
    int instances {0};
    std::cin >> instances;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();

    for(int i{0}; i<instances; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Instancia " << i+1 << "\n";
        Sudoku<Constants::ROW_COL_SIZE> sudokuInstance;
        sudokuInstance.ReadRows();
        if(sudokuInstance.IsValid()) {
            std::cout << Constants::STR_YES;
        } else {
            std::cout << Constants::STR_NO;
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2 things: (1) _"...My gut tells me..."_ measure (profile) it; with modern optimizing compilers, pre-fetchers and out-of-order execution your gut is highly unreliable.  (2) Why template the size of the board when the rest of the code relies on the board being a fixed size?

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm a beginner, my initial thoughts were to to use `N` everywhere as `9` instead of using a constant defined somewhere `constexpr int size = 9`. The functionality should also be that with better/more implementation a multiple of `3` sudoku grids should be solvable with the same class.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have a 3*3 array of blocks so something like this should work:

```
for ( int row = 0; row < 3; row++ )
{
   for ( int column = 0; column < 3; column++ )
   {
      if (!ValidateOneBlock(row * 3, row * 3 + 2, column * 3, column * 3 + 2))
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
return true;
```

You presumably need another loop to validate the lines:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
{
  if (!ValidateOneBlock(i, i, 0, 8))
  {
    return false;
  }
  if (!ValidateOneBlock(0, 8, i, i))
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but something along the following lines should work, for any `N`, assuming `N` is a multiple of 3. Actually I think it is better to parameterize `Sudoku` on the number of 'blocks' in both dimensions, instead of the number of values along one dimension. That will lift this specific requirement on `N`. Calculating the Cartesian product (`cellCoordinates`) is a nice candidate for further generalization.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>

...

template<unsigned int N>
bool Sudoku<N>::IsValid() const
{
  // 9bit default ctor all zeroes, 000000000
  std::bitset<N> bitRow[N];
  std::bitset<N> bitCol[N];
  for (unsigned int i{0}; i < N; i++)
  {
    for (unsigned int j{0}; j < N; j++)
    {
      bitRow[i].flip(m_matrix[i][j] - 1);  // bitset index is 0 not 1.
      bitCol[i].flip(m_matrix[j][i] - 1);
    }
    if (!bitRow[i].all() || !bitCol[i].all())
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  static_assert(N % 3 == 0, "N should be a multiple of 3");
  std::array<int, N / 3> indices;
  std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);

  std::array<std::pair<int, int>, N> cellCoordinates;
  auto curr = cellCoordinates.begin();
  for (int i : indices)
    for (int j : indices)
      *curr++ = std::pair(i, j);

  return std::all_of(
      cellCoordinates.begin(), cellCoordinates.end(), [this](const auto& c) {
        const int rowStart{c.first * 3};
        const int rowEnd{rowStart + 2};
        const int colStart{c.second * 3};
        const int colEnd{colStart + 2};
        return ValidateOneBlock(rowStart, rowEnd, colStart, colEnd);
      });
}
```